# Why does this script move all files instead of just the newest files?

Tags: python

```
import os
import datetime
import shutil

source = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Files to move/'
destination = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Delete Logs/'

today = datetime.datetime.today() # Get current time

# Create log file with datestamp
file=open(logging_path+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')+'.txt', 'a')

# Move files
allfiles = os.listdir(source)
for f in allfiles:
    # Check last modified time
    t = os.stat(os.path.join(f, source))[8]
    filetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) - today

    # Is file less than a day old? If yes, move.
    if filetime.days <= 1:
        print(os.path.join(f, source), filetime.days)
        file.write(os.path.join(f, source) + ' created ' + str(-1 * filetime.days)+' day(s) ago has moved\n')
        shutil.move(source + f, destination + f)
```

Like the title says, I wrote this trying to move files less than a day old to a new location on a different disk but it moves all files in the location instead of the newest files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you correctly joining your paths for printing using `os.path.join`, but use the `+` operator for `shutil.move`?

Comment: Also, by the way, the common `find` utility can do all this on its own ;)

Comment: I'd guess because your `filetime` is strange; why are you doing it so complicated using `os.stat(…)[8]` instead of  [getctime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime)?

Comment: This is part of a bigger script I made to delete files as well, I copied parts of my delete script and added the `shutil.move` but clearly I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm very much a beginner just following tutorials I've found on the internet.

Comment: so far it looks quite OK, but now you're deep into the land where it helps when you read the documentation of the functions you're using! Luckily, python.org has the documentation for all of these, as I linked to above for getctime, as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, you just need to add '-' sign before the last condition, because the output of `filetime.days` is `-1`, your condition will be :

```
if -filetime.days <= 1:
```

And you have inversed between source and filename just after the for loop

```
import os
import datetime
import shutil

source = 'f2/'
destination = 'f1/'

today = datetime.datetime.today() # Get current time

# Create log file with datestamp
file=open(logging_path+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')+'.txt', 'a')

# Move files
allfiles = os.listdir(source)
for f in allfiles:
    # Check last modified time
    t = os.stat(os.path.join(source, f))[8]
    filetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) - today
    print (filetime.days, type(filetime.days), t, f)

    # Is file less than a day old? If yes, move.
    if -filetime.days <= 1:   # ==============> Here 
        print(os.path.join(f, source), filetime.days)
        file.write(os.path.join(f, source) + ' created ' + str(-1 * filetime.days)+' day(s) ago has moved\n')
        shutil.move(source + f, destination + f)
```

Comment: Oh dear lawd. That was too simple of a fix. Thank you very much.